# Как задавать FPS динамически при кодировании кадров с веб-камеры в vp8 в реальном времени

Tags: c++, видео, libvpx

Нужно организовать стрим в браузер с веб-камеры с межкадровым сжатием. Поскольку h264 не поддерживается в Chromium браузерах, кодирую в vp8. Так как веб-камера не может выдавать стабильный FPS из-за различных условий съёмки и количества поступающего на матрицу света, возникает вопрос - **как задать vpx кодеку время показа индивидуально для каждого кадра?**
Инициализация кодека походит так:

```
bool Codec::Open(unsigned int width, unsigned int height){
    if(!vpx_img_alloc(&frame, VPX_IMG_FMT_I420, width, height, 1)){
        cout << "Img alloc error\n";
        return false;
    }
    if( vpx_codec_enc_config_default(vpx_codec_vp8_cx(), &cfg, 0) != VPX_CODEC_OK){
        vpx_img_free(&frame);
        cout << "Def conf set error\n";
        return false;
    }
    cfg.g_timebase.den = 20;
    cfg.g_timebase.num = 1;
    cfg.rc_min_quantizer = 20;
    cfg.rc_max_quantizer = 50;
    cfg.g_w = width;
    cfg.g_h = height;
    cfg.rc_target_bitrate = cfg.g_w * cfg.g_h * cfg.rc_target_bitrate;
    if( vpx_codec_enc_init(&ctx, vpx_codec_vp8_cx(), &cfg, 0) != VPX_CODEC_OK){
        vpx_img_free(&frame);
        cout << "Codec init error\n";
        return false;
    }
    frames = 0;
    return true;
}
```

Процесс кодирования кадра:

```
std::string Codec::Encode(unsigned char *source){
    std::string result("");
    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = NULL;
    const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt;
    colorspaces::BGRtoI420(cfg.g_w, cfg.g_h, source, &frame.planes[0], &frame.planes[1], &frame.planes[2]);
    if( vpx_codec_encode(&ctx, &frame, frames, 1, 0, VPX_DL_REALTIME) != VPX_CODEC_OK){return result;}
    while(pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(&ctx, &iter)){
        if( pkt->kind == VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT){
            result+= write_ivf_frame_header(pkt);
            result.append((char*)(pkt->data.frame.buf), pkt->data.frame.sz);
        }
    }
    frames++;
    return result;
}
```

Есть идея снимать серию кадров с расчётом среднего значения FPS и потом отправлять пакет кадров на кодирование в параллельном потоке, но тогда придётся каждый раз заново инициализировать кодировщик и устанавливать другие параметры FPS (`cfg.g_timebase.den`). Может у кого есть идеи получше?

Comment: "веб-камера не может выдавать стабильный FPS из-за различных условий съёмки и количества поступающего на матрицу света" какое интересное утверждение.

Comment: @VTT, ну, оно получено опытным путём - 60 пользователей в разных офисах, и с разными ноутами/компами, с разными камерами. Сейчас система отправляет JPEG кадры (покадровое сжатие), а для экономии пропускной способности интернет-канала нужно перевести на межкадровое сжатие.

Comment: @VTT, а что удивительного-то? Это факт. Попробуйте позаписывать кадры с камеры и посмотрите, что с таймстампами.

Comment: @Iceman, вы можете буферизировать кадры. Таймстамп нового кадра вы вполне можете посчитать. В случае задержки, которую вы сами определите, подсовываете предыдущий кадр на кодирование. Так вы избежите проблемы с изменением fps и переинициализацией. Вы к кадрам камеры как доступ получаете?

Comment: @user1056837, кадры получаю через самописный класс на базе vfw32. Технология старая, но зато с ней заводится любая камера на любой винде, а с OpenCV были случаи отказа работать с некоторыми девайсами, которые при этом легко работали с тем же скайпом и алгоритмами на основе vfw

Comment: @Iceman, я с v4l работал, но подозреваю, что принцип должен быть похож. Выбираете разумные настройки для камеры (чтобы меньше пришлось манипуляций с кадром совершать), а потом буферизуете.

Comment: @user1056837, проблема в том, что моим приложением пользуются несколько десятков сотрудников, и у всех разные, как правило встроенные в ноут, камеры. В этих камерах в большинстве случаев нельзя даже выдержку изменить, поэтому нужно универсальное решение.

Comment: @Iceman, тогда я не понимаю вопрос. В исходном вопросе одна камера. Теперь камеры появились у каждого сотрудника. Если вы про _неуниверсальность_ выбора настроек камеры, то это делается перед инициализацией кодека. В v4l можно получить от камеры все поддерживаемые ей режимы (в vfw32 обязан быть аналог). После этого вы их сортируете, выбираете нужный и потом инициализируете кодек. Вот вам и универсальность. Как отсортировать - это уже вопрос к вам. Что вам важнее? Можете сначала настройки по допустимому fps просеять, или по цветовому пространству. Тут уж на что фантазии хватит.

Answer (score 0):

Получается, для компенсации нестабильного FPS, который выдаёт камера, к глобальному PTS нужно приращивать отношение полученной задержки кадра к задержке эталонного FPS. То есть, при 25 FPS задержка будет 1000/25=40 мс, и если мы получили кадр например за 80 мс, то к PTS нужно добавить 2: `PTS+=(int) (80/40)`. Не знаю, нормально это или нет, но так запись длится ровно столько, сколько и съёмка, без опережения и с теми же таймингами кадров (хотя размер файла несколько увеличивается).