# Параметр Presentation timestamp и контроль FPS при кодировании VP8

Tags: c++, libvpx

В контексте [данного вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766868/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-fps-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B2-vp8-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE) хочу прояснить для себя специфику таких параметров VPX-кодека, как `pts` (Presentation time stamp) и `duration` структуры `vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t.frame`, а также их взаимодействие с FPS, указанным в заголовке видео-контейнера.

Функция кодирования выглядит так:

```
std::string Codec::Encode(unsigned char *source, unsigned int timing){
    std::string result("");
    vpx_codec_iter_t iter = NULL;
    const vpx_codec_cx_pkt_t *pkt;
    colorspaces::BGRtoI420(cfg.g_w, cfg.g_h, source, &frame.planes[0], &frame.planes[1], &frame.planes[2]);
    if( vpx_codec_encode(&ctx, &frame, PTS, timing, 0, VPX_DL_REALTIME) != VPX_CODEC_OK){return result;}
    while(pkt = vpx_codec_get_cx_data(&ctx, &iter)){
        if( pkt->kind == VPX_CODEC_CX_FRAME_PKT){
            result+= write_ivf_frame_header(pkt);
            result.append((char*)(pkt->data.frame.buf), pkt->data.frame.sz);
        }
    }
    PTS++;
    return result;
}
```

Параметр `timing` это время захвата кадра в миллисекундах, полученное при помощи `GetTickCount()` или `clock()`, например так:

```
unsigned int Camera::Grab(unsigned char **framebuf, unsigned int *timing = nullptr){
    unsigned int size, start = GetTickCount(); // defining operation start time
    unsigned long result;
    WaitForSingleObject(M_Camera, INFINITE);
    FrameData = *framebuf;
    SendMessageTimeoutA(CaptureWindow,WM_CAP_GRAB_FRAME,0,0,SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG,500,&result);
    if( result ){size = FrameSize;}
    else{size = 0;}
    FrameData = nullptr;
    ReleaseMutex(M_Camera);
    if( timing != nullptr){*timing = GetTickCount() - start; /* setting elapsed time if needed*/}
    return size;
}
```

Если глобальный `PTS` увеличивать не на 1, а приращивать к нему время захвата кадра (`timing`), то воспроизведение замедляется. Проблема в том, что замедляется оно очень сильно, а вот `duration`, не смотря на описание ("duration to show frame (in timebase units)") вообще никак не влияет на частоту смены кадра.

1. Что подразумевается под "timebase units" в `vpx_codec_pts_t pts; /*time stamp to show frame (in timebase units)*/`? Это кадры, секунды, миллисекунды, наносекунды?? Как его выставлять при нестабильном FPS?
2. Почему `unsigned long duration; /*duration to show frame (in timebase units)*/` не делает ничего, как им не крути? Неправильно использую?
3. Можно ли вообще этими параметрами влиять на FPS и сделать его "плавающим", или я не в том направлении копаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, тут речь идет о единицах, задаваемых в [vpx_codec_enc_cfg::g_timebase](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/webm-sdk/structvpx__codec__enc__cfg.html#a6498d378e4c29ef3e22258289e481087). этот `timebase` представляет собой рациональную дробь, выражающую время в долях от секунды. Распространенные значения для этой величины можно посмотреть [тут, в табличке preset](http://avisynth.nl/index.php/FPS). В знаменателе пишется частота некоторого абстрактного (или реального) тактового генератора (Гц), в числителе пишется количество тактов, которые формируют один интервал. В PTS пишется количество таких интервалов, прошедшее с начала записи, когда надо показать конкретный кадр. А в duration количество таких интервалов, в течении которых следует показывать текущий кадр. Надо полагать, что PTS имеет приоритет.

Пример: если `timebase` стоит 1001 / 24000, то интервал будет ~42 мс. А приращивая PTS, скажем, по 3, каждый кадр будет демонстрироваться по (3 * 1001) / 24000 = ~125 мс.

По идее, там конечно можно выставить `timebase` и 1 / 1000, то бишь 1 мс, и выставлять PTS в миллисекундах. Но идея определять fps по времени получения кадра мне кажется сомнительной.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение! Удалось синхронизировать съёмку и кодирование с записью.